# Retrieve json data in Angular controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I'd like to get a couple of values out of a JSON file in my app controller.

I have a JSON file that looks something like this:

```
{
   "login": [
      {
         "username": "admin",
         "password": "admin"
      }
    ],
    "header": [
       {
          "subTitle": "Hello",
          "color": "red"
        }
    ]
 }
```

I am attempting to retrieve a value like this:

```
app.controller('loginCtrl', function($http, $scope) {
   data = $http.get('data.json');
   console.log(data.login.username);
}
```

However, all I'm getting in the console is `TypeError: Cannot read property 'username' of undefined`.

Comment: Read about `then()`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
data = $http.get('data.json');
data.then(function(result){
    console.log(result.login[0].username);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Even though your javascript is synchronous,the call you make is always asynch

```
 $http.get('data.json').then(function (response) {
console.log(response.data)
});
```

So in your terms javascript called the get function and before it returned with result it executed this `console.log(data.login.username);` 
So you did not got the expected result

Comment: Thanks, but I'm getting 'undefined' in the console.

Comment: Why negative anyone who gave negative please explain what i said wrong..